# Non-awaited async methods run on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to have a method (Let's call it **M1**) execute some `async` code in a loop (Let's call that second method **M2**). On every iteration - the UI should be updated with the result of **M2**.

In order to await **M2**, **M1** needs to be `async`. But **M1** should run on the UI thread (to avoid race conditions) and therefore it will be called without an `await`.

Am I correct in thinking that in this way, **M1**'s updating of the UI will be on the UI thread?

---

<sub>(**Extra**: It seems OK to have an `async void` in this case. Is this correct?)</sub>

Comment: Yes, seems you are correct. Just try to do it.

Comment: Trying would be tricky because race conditions are usually unlikely in this case. I'm just being careful because someone _sometime_ will likely run into them.

Comment: @ispiro btw, if you want to try `Task.Delay(10)` is likely the easiest way to create truly async method.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for your time. I'm now looking into this whole thing. I really don't understand what's the point in async if it doesn't run on another thread. Anyway, I'm reading up on that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. (assuming you use Synchronization Context that returns to UI thread - i.e. one from WinForm/WPF).

Note that it also means you can't schedule CPU-intensive operations that way as it will run on UI thread.

Using `void async` is quite standard method of handling events in WinForms:

```
void async click_RunManyAsync(...)
{
   await M1();
}

void async M1()
{
     foreach (...)
     {
        var result = await M2(); 
        uiElement.Text = result; 
     }
}

async Task<string> M2()
{
    // sync portion runs on UI thread
    // don't perform a lot of CPU-intensive work

    // off main thread, same synchronization context - so sync part will be on UI thread. 
    var result = await SomeReallyAsyncMethod(...); 

    // sync portion runs on UI thread
    // don't perform a lot of CPU-intensive work
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not explicitly using any Synchronization Context and I'm using this in UWP - Windows Universal Apps. Is that still OK?

Comment: Yes, the principle is the same

Comment: I don't understand your example - Since M1 is awaited - it will _not_ run on the UI thread. Isn't that so?

Comment: @ispiro - It will use current context - if starting operation on UI thread than it will come back to UI thread, if one from thread pool - will continue on arbitrary  thread.

Comment: But won't the `await` create a new thread for M1 so that `uiElement` will be updated from that second thread?

Comment: @ispiro, the Synchronization Context is set by UI framework. It is guaranteed that M1 and M2 will both run on UI thread.

Comment: @ispiro `await` *does not* change what thread synchronous part of the code runs - so anything up to `await SomeReallyAsyncMethod` call will be on original thread. Synchronization context decides where execution continue after asynchronous operation ends.

Comment: @isipro, No, `await` will not create a new thread (using the Syncronization Context provided by UI) unless you order to create it manually using `await Task.Run(... cpu-bound code...)`.

Comment: OK. So it seems I misunderstood the whole `await` thing. So a) I _don't_ need to remove the `await` from M1. b) Any long calculations done in an `async` method _will_ stop the UI (unless using `Task.Run`). Did I understand correctly now? [I now see that I've been reading comments by two people. And they seem contradictory.]

Comment: @ispiro sounds right (but I don't see Andrey's and my comments are contradicting each other - so there is likely something else :)) I'd recommend searching for something like "C# await new thread" on search engine of your choice to read more. I.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429294/how-different-is-await-async-from-threading, consider asking separate question if need more clarification as it would be better than long comment thread...