# Async call on GUI event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I've an event on an UserControl(winform) that I'm listening:

```
public void OnSomething(SomeEventArgs args){
    SomeResult result = ?await? _businessObject.AsyncCall();
    ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult(result);
}
```

`_businessObject.AsyncCall()` has the following signature:

```
public async Task<SomeResult> AsyncCall();
```

How can I call this async method while:

1. Not blocking the GUI thread
2. Being able to call the `ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult` after my async method has been called
3. Being able to call the `ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult` in the correct(GUI) thread.

What I tried:

```
public void OnSomething(SomeEventArgs args){
    SomeResult result = await _businessObject.AsyncCall();
    ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult(result);
}
```

--> Doesn't compile since my event handler isn't async.

```
public void OnSomething(SomeEventArgs args){
    SomeResult result = _businessObject.AsyncCall().Result;
    ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult(result);
}
```

--> The application freeze

```
public void OnSomething(SomeEventArgs args){
    _businessObject.AsyncCall().ContinueWith(t=>{
        if(InvokeRequired){
            Invoke(new Action(()=>ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult(t.Result)));
        }
    });
}
```

--> Works, but I was hopping that there was a nicer way to do it with the async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to mark your handler as `async`:

```
public async void OnSomething(SomeEventArgs args)
{
    SomeResult result = await _businessObject.AsyncCall();
    ApplySomethingOnTheGuiBasedOnTheResult(result);
}
```

I know it's not recommended to use `asyc` with return type `void` (normally it should be `Task` or `Task<sometype>`), but if the event requires that signature, it's the only way.

This way the control flow is returned to the caller at the `await` statement. When the `AsyncCall` has finished, execution is eventually resumed *after* the `await` on the UI thread.

Comment: I just want to stress to the OP and future readers, the only place you should ever write `async void` is when you are doing a event handler like this. If you are not writing a event handler you should be doing `async Task`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain right, I was adding that while you commented.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to set the event handler methods as async, thank you :)