# C# WPF Indeterminate progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf

Please could someone suggest why the following doesn't work? All I want to do is display an indeterminate progress bar which starts when the button is clicked, then after I've done some work I set the indeterminate progress bar to false to stop it.

However when I run the code below the indeterminate progress bar doesn't even start. I tried commenting out the line `this.progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false` and when I do this the progress bar does start but then doesn't terminate.

```
private void GenerateCSV_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate ()
    {
        this.progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

        // do some work
        Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);

        this.progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Obviously, if you tell the UI thread to sleep, it won't be able to display the indeterminate progress bar during that time...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code can't work because the "do some work" is happening on the same `Thread` on which the UI works. So, if that `Thread` is busy with the "work", how can it handle the UI animation for the `ProgressBar` at the same time?
You have to put the "work" on another `Thread`, so the `UI Thread` is free and can do its job with the `ProgressBar` (or other UI controls).

1) create a method that does the work and returns a `Task`, so it can be "awaited" for completion:

```
private async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do some work HERE
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    });
}
```

2) Put the `async` modifier on the `GenerateCSV_Click`:

```
private async void GenerateCSV_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

3) throw away all that "Dispatcher" / "Invoke" etc stuffs, and use the `DoWorkAsync` this way:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PB.IsIndeterminate = true;

    await DoWorkAsync();

    PB.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

So, what's happening now? When `GenerateCSV_Click` encounters the first `await`... it begins to work automatically on another `Thread`, leaving the `UI Thread` free to operate and animate the `ProgressBar`.
When the work is finished, the control of the method returns to the `UI Thread` that sets the `IsIndeterminate` to false.

Here you can find the MSDN tutorial on `async` programming:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx
If you Google "C# async await", you'll find dozens of tutorials, examples and explanations ;)

Comment: @edb500 you can verify that the async/await pattern dispatches the work on different Threads by putting "Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);" before, inside, and after the "await DoWorkAsync": you will see in the OutputWindow the different Thread Ids on which the statements are called.

Comment: I am using this exact same configuration for my project however, when I do : PB.IsIndeterminate = false , I get the exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  (I am using the Xceed.WpfToolKits for my progress bar). Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @NicolasR, how you declare and use `PB`? Sure it is not instantiated, and that's why you get that NullReferenceException. In my example, `PB` is the name I gave to my ProgressBar: `<ProgressBar Name="PB" ...` in the xaml file. This way, in the xaml.cs I can call `PB.IsIndeterminate`, because it has been automatically instantiated in the "hidden constructor" for me.

Comment: I am declaring it in my xaml file as well. I have no problem with PB.IsIndeterminate = true (and with other variables as well for that matters), only with PB;IsIndeterminate = false (but only if it is called after I set it to true), that is why I don't understand the exception

Comment: @NicolasR you should post an entire question, it's not possible to help you in such a small place as a comment :) 
Link this question in yours, if you want.

Comment: OK, I got it, turns out that I was using some other UI's values (TextBox and such) in my DoWorkAsync function (and you definitely do not want to do that) and I was not using the Thread.Sleep()

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Could you please clarify? Is your  `Button_Click` event actually OP's `GenerateCSV_Click` method?

Comment: @nam yes it is. I just created a more general example.