# c# WPF Xceed ProgressBar IsIndeterminate Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, xceed

I am trying to use the ProgressBarCircular from Xceed.WpfToolKit without success.

I followed the following question to help me make it work : [C# WPF Indeterminate progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196709/c-sharp-wpf-indeterminate-progress-bar/39196946?noredirect=1#comment76578625_39196946)

so my code now looks like that :

```
private async void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
    await DoWorkAsync();
    this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;   
}


private async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
           // do my work (using my WPF mainWindow Fields)
        });
    });
}
```

However I keep having the Exception :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the line

```
this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

Seeing how I declare ProgressBar in my xaml file and the line

```
this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
```

works perfectly fine (and if IsIndeterminate = false is declared before it is set to true, I have no problem either), I don't understand what might cause this exception.

### Solution

It turned out that I was using some others UI's value (like TextBox.Text) in my DoWorkAsync functions and I was not using Thread.Sleep(1000) in the function as well, so ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate did not have time to change its value twice and thus threw the exception

Comment: I guess something happens in the setter of the *IsIndeterminate* property (although, there is still a remote chance that *this.ProgressBar* itself somehow became `null`). Look at the exception stacktrace... For more information of how to troubleshoot NullReferenceExceptions, see here: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Which control are you referring to? Please provide a link to whatever "ProgressBarCircular" control you are using. Does your code if you are using the built-in ProgressBar control?