# Is there any difference between "await SaveChangesAsync()" and "SaveChanges()"? They seem to do the same thing

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

My understanding is that

```
await myContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

will save the changes, but not allow the thread to continue in the same manner that

```
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

behaves.

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: [If async-await doesn't create any additional threads, then how does it make applications responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419572)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If async-await doesn't create any additional threads, then how does it make applications responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

Answer (score 3):

> allow the thread to continue

This is your misunderstanding.

Put simply, synchronous methods like `SaveChanges` block the calling thread until the method completes.

Asynchronous methods like `SaveChangesAsync` (when consumed with `await`) will not block the calling thread. The `await` will "pause" the method, but it will not block the thread.

You can find more information about how this works in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post and my post on [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: So basically, you are saying that the using "await" will pause the current method, but the parent thread that called this method will continue onward without a pause?

Comment: @user7560542 Yes. See my async intro post for more info.