# How does a toolbar button know to await?

Tags: .net, xamarin

If I have this...

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem  Text = "Done" Clicked="Done_Clicked" />
    <ToolbarItem Text = "Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

In the code behind...

```
async void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

How does the tool bar item know that its handler is asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It doesn't***, you need to use a 3rd party library that provides async commands. Personally I like [Nito.Mvvm.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-pre-03), it gives you a AsyncCommand you can use and bind your functions to. The button will be disabled while the async function runs and will re-enable once the function is complete.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text = "Done" Command="{Binding DoneCommand}" />
    <ToolbarItem Text = "Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

in your view moodel.

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    CancelCommand = new AsyncCommand(ExecuteCancel);
}

public AsyncCommand CancelCommand {get;}

async Task ExecuteCancel()
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

---

Here is a more complex version that disables the cancel option unless the Done option is currently running.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text = "Done" Command="{Binding DoneCommand}" />
    <ToolbarItem Text = "Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

in your view moodel.

```
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DoneCommand = new AsyncCommand(ExecuteDone);
        CancelCommand = new CustomAsyncCommand(ExecuteCancel, CanExecuteCancel);
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(DoneCommand, (sender, e) => CancelCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged(), nameof(DoneCommand.IsExecuting));
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(CancelCommand, (sender, e) => CancelCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged(), nameof(CancelCommand.IsExecuting));
    }

    private bool CanExecuteCancel()
    {
        return DoneCommand.IsExecuting && !CancelCommand.IsExecuting;
    }

    public AsyncCommand DoneCommand { get; }
    public CustomAsyncCommand CancelCommand { get; }

    async Task ExecuteDone()
    {
        await ... //Do stuff

    }

    async Task ExecuteCancel()
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Cancel_Clicked` handler returns `void` so your toolbar item (UI Thread) can't know if your method is asynchronous.

*Edit:*
Inner method **PopModalAsync()** will run *asynchronously* - it will finish work in some time in the future. **Cancel_Clicked()** will return immediately, and for UI thread it is synchronous operation.

Comment: So, it's called synchronously?

Comment: That should give you some view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl

Comment: I don't see the relevance.

Comment: I've added an additional comment. Also there are a lot of docs about how async/await work in details.