# Can different task run in same thread concurrent at same time?

Tags: c#, task

I have the situation that I need an exclusive singleton for each ***task*** I run. Currently I use *[ThreadStatic]* attribute to keep the singleton's instance for each thread separately. But: Can I count on that more than one task is never run in same thread at same time? ... otherwise my singleton would be shared between these tasks.

Comment: I'd recommend having a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

Comment: It would be more readable to pass expected values as parameters to async method instead of using singletons.

Comment: Depends to a great extent on *how* the `Task`s are going to be completed which is very much an implementation detail that deliberately isn't really part of the `Task` contract. `Task` objects are an abstraction for ongoing work. For instance, it's perfectly valid for a thread to be running some code in which it has an array of `TaskCompletionSource` objects and marks each one as complete in a loop. Does that mean that all of those tasks were "running" on that thread? That's a philosophical question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if each task needs its own 'singleton', why not use a separate class for each task which contains its own properties? The Task start point could be a method in the class. Or is the static field also used by methods outside the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about CPU bound tasks e.g. `Task.Run` and equivalent.

The TPL can inline tasks in a variety of circumstances. This can cause multiple tasks to be on the same thread and stack. For example, `Task.Wait` can run the task argument if it has not been started and the scheduler allows it.

The TPL is absolutely full of such reentrancy where a seemingly harmless call such as `Task.Wait` or `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` can run *arbitrary* code. This is in my view a very nasty design bug. And it's causing lots of practical issues. I'm sometimes reading the coreclr/corefx commit logs and I regularly find bug fixes there for issues causes by TPL reentrancy.

Comment: I see, this means, it can happen, that the task objects can exist side by side in the same thread. I think I have to reconsider my design again (either using thread class instead task class or passing all stuff around ..). Thank you!