# Access UI Control on UI Thread using async & a event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await

I am writing a WPF Form Application, in which i am trying to Loop through a FOLDER and show its files REAL TIME, using Async await approach. Within my ***Task.Run()*** method I am Raising my event, which raises fine, however that event code also **updates a TEXT BOX**, which is on **UI Thread**, hence i am getting UI Thread Error

> 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.'

. Is there any way to change my code so I can update my TextBox?

```
    private delegate void GetFilesCount(string f);
    private event GetFilesCount onFileCount;


    private void Btn_Compare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        onFileCount += FileCount;
        CountFilesAsync();
    }


    function async void CountFilesAsync() {
            await Task.Run(()=> {
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
                foreach (FileInfo item in myDir.GetFiles())
                {
                    onFileCount(item.Name); // This is an EVENT
                } 

            });
}
```

and my event Handler Code

```
    private void FileCount(string fileName)
    {
            txtLabel_Log.Text = fileName;   // < -- Calling Method UI Error
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you, but you could trying invoking your applications dispatcher.

```
private void FileCount(string fileName)
{
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            txtLabel_Log.Text = fileName;   // < -- Calling Method UI Error
        });
}
```

Comment: You're not an idiot, we all have to learn some how. I'm glad your problem is fixed

Answer (score 2):

[Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

```
private void Btn_Compare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CountFilesAsync(Progress<string>(FileCount));
}

private async void CountFilesAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (FileInfo item in myDir.GetFiles())
            {
                progress(item.Name); // report progress
            } 
        });
}
```