# Async HTML Parse with Beautifulsoup4 in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, beautifulsoup

I'm making a python web scraper script. I should do this using asyncio. So for Async HTTP request I use AioHTTP.
It's ok but when i'm trying to make a non-blocking app (await), the beautifulsoup4 will block application (because beautifulsoup4  dose't support async)

This is what i'm tried.

```
import asyncio, aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

async def extractLinks(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup.select(".c-pro-box__title a")

async def getHtml(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def loadPage(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await getHtml(session, url)
        links = await extractLinks(html)
        return links

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(loadPage())
```

The `extractLinks()` will block program flow.
So is this possible to make it non-blocking? Or is there any library except beautifulsoup4 that support async as well as possible?

Comment: Somewhere some function has to be blocking to get things done, you can't escape it. The purpose of async is to reduce waiting for IO, not CPU work.

Comment: `extractLinks` is a "working function" that uses the CPU, it doesn't do anything async by nature (like sending HTTP request or reading from a DB). if you want to can execute it on a new thread, but that's a different issue

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Thanks you. I did't know that async is just for IO and parsing just uses CPU. And your suggest about  using thread is very nice. I'll do it.

Comment: @abdusco thanks you. i did't know that async just for IO

Comment: I suggest reading this question and the answers to it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37419572/5052365

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Based on your question, I understand that you are looking to enhance your code performance.

So according to your shorter details, I'll provide a shorter response as well.

1. There's no `Async` HTML parser due to the fact that the native code is based on `regex` and other operations based on I/O.
2. You are using `BeautifulSoup` with `html.parser` which is way slower than `lxml` [Refference](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Also I highly recommend to use `selectolax` with `Lexbor` due to high performance with code built over `C` [Check](https://selectolax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lexbor.html)
3. use `httpx` instead of `aiohttp`. (due to technical performance based on `C`)
4. use `trio` which is high level API of `Async`

Below code should be helpful for your use case.

```py
import httpx
from selectolax.lexbor import LexborHTMLParser
import trio

links = []


async def get_soup(content):
    return LexborHTMLParser(content)


async def worker(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for client, link in channel:
            r = await client.get(link)
            soup = await get_soup(r.content)
            # continue from here!


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(10):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for link in links:
                    await sender.send([client, link])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```