# Which thread continue after await?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I run this code on a thread pool.

```cs
public static class AsyncClass
{
    public static async Task Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Before Test - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await ReturnInstantly();
        Console.WriteLine($"After Test - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }

    private static async Task ReturnInstantly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ReturnInstantly1 - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await Task.Yield();
        Console.WriteLine($"ReturnInstantly2 - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine($"ReturnInstantly3 - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Before Test - 1
ReturnInstantly1 - 1
ReturnInstantly2 - 4
ReturnInstantly3 - 4
After Test - 4
```

Is the continuation after `await` always on the thread that finished processed the method we are waiting for (`ReturnInstantly`), or can it be continued on any thread, and this situation is a matter of optimization?

**Edit 1:**
Which thread charts is correct? (or all of them)

Horizontal axis: time,

Vertical axis: nesting level,

Colors: different threads,

Vertical arrows: a thread is borrowed from the pool.

1. [image: first]
2. [image: second]
3. [image: third]
4. [image: fourth]
5. [image: fifth]

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't rely on it being one way or the other - seems to be an implementation detail.

Comment: By default, it resumes in the same SynchronizationContext. You say that your code is running in the thread pool. The thread pool's SynchronizationContext resumes in the thread pool. (No guarantee which thread in the thread pool.)

Comment: @RaymondChen As I understand it, the question is whether *each* incomplete `await` will change the thread (when this is what the synchronization context does), or will it happen only at the most nested `await`. Here `Test()` awaits `ReturnInstantly()`, and `ReturnInstantly()` awaits `Task.Delay()`. The inner await is incomplete, so the thread changes there. But the outer await (the `await ReturnInstantly()`) is also incomplete, but the thread does not change there. Is it an implementation detail, or a coincidence, or indeed the thread change affects the entire `await` chain as a whole?

Comment: It depends on the SynchronizationContext of the thread you are calling await on. If you execute await on the UI thread of a WinForms (WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext) or WPF (DispatcherSynchronizationContext) app, the code will continue on the UI thread after await. I'm not aware of other SynchronizationContexts that guarantee the continuation on the same thread. That is the case for example in the main thread of a console application by default. Also, Task.ConfigureAwait(false) would let await continue on another thread.

Comment: @RaymondChen, so last output "After Test - 4", can looks like "After Test - 6", or different threadId which is free (1,2,5.7 ...)?

Comment: If you care about which thread you're on, use a synchronization context that provides the guarantees you need. Otherwise, if it's not actually important to the correctness of the code, *why worry*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever its not important, but i'm curious and i want to know :D

Comment: The "After Test - 4" could be "After Test - <any thread in the thread pool>". You're seeing an internal optimization to avoid unnecessary thread switches, but it is not contractual, and the optimization could change at any time, say, for NUMA-awareness. In theory, every `await` could switch to a different threadpool thread. (I don't understand the thread chart. Horizontal axis is time, I assume. What is vertical axis? What do the colors mean? What do the vertical arrows mean?)

Comment: @RaymondChen Vertical axis: nesting level. Colors: different threads. Vertical arrows: a thread is borrowed from the pool.

Comment: RaymondChen, my mistake. Exactly as @GSerg said. Thanks :)
So I understand, that all chart is correct?

Comment: In the third chart, it looks like Test is resuming before ReturnInstantly completes, which is wrong. The `await` in Test does not resume execution until ReturnInstantly completes.

Comment: @RaymondChen In the third chart the `Test`'s thread is sitting around waiting to resume on itself when `ReturnInstantly` completes on its own thread - which I believe doesn't happen either like Stephen Cleary noted below.

Comment: Test's original thread is returned to the thread pool when idle. Test doesn't hold the thread hostage. (That would basically defeat the purpose of a thread pool.)

Comment: In a now ♦-deleted answer, Stephen Cleary says that charts 1 and 2 are possible.

Comment: @RaymondChen
In the third chart i try to simulate a situation when the green thread didn't make `await`, and the blue return faster. 


I add 4, and 5 chart. It better illustrates situation. I think 4 is wrong, and 5 is correct because, blue come back, checks `await`, and continue executing the `Test`.